# Accessing ActiveX control from Module

Tags: excel, vba

I guess I have my basic wrong here, can anybody please correct me?

I have an ActiveX control in "home" worksheet. Now, when I code,

**This works:**

```
MsgBox (ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("home").quantity.Value)
```

**So does this:**

```
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("home")
    MsgBox (.quantity.Value)
End With
```

**But this does not:**

```
Dim wh As Worksheet
Set wh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("home")
MsgBox (wh.quantity.Value)
```

Can anybody please explain the difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Worksheet` class does not have a `quantity` member so the compiler will object to it. You either need to use an Object variable (as in both of your prior examples), or access the control using the `OLEobjects` property of the worksheet:

```
MsgBox wh.OLEObjects("quantity").Object.Value
```

for example.